# Data Percent Attribute Value Change

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-apps-script

I am trying to have a dynamic value for the data percent attribute. The value is dependant on a html selection. The selection will retreive the data from the google sheet and then display it in the bar graph.

However the value is being brought through but not altering the bar graph.

The script I have to bring the data into the data percent attribute is as follows:

```
$('#test').data('data-percent', change);
```

I have included my whole code to allow a greater understanding.

Below is the html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<div class="wrap">
  <h1>Projects Status</h1>
  <form id="contact">

          <select id="projectNoView" name="jobNumber" type="text" tabindex="1" onchange="populate()" required>
         </select>
         
    <script>
      (function () {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
          function (selectList) {
            var select = document.getElementById("projectNoView");
            for( var i=0; i<selectList.length; i++ ) {
              var option = document.createElement("option");
              option.text = selectList[i][0];
              select.add(option);
            }
          }
        ).getSelectList();
      }());
    </script>
         </form>
<div class="holder">
<h2>To be Completed by the Commissioning Engineer</h2>
<div id = "test" class="bar" data-percent="25%"><span class="label">NICEIC Testing</span></div>

</div>

<script>
window.addEventListener('load', populate());

function populate(){
  var formObject = document.getElementById("projectNoView");
  var result = formObject.options[formObject.selectedIndex].text;
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(displayValue).fetchValues(result);
}

function displayValue(data){
var change = data[0][0];
$('.label').text(change); // to display the value in span
document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('data-percent', '100%')
}

</script>

<script>
     setTimeout(function start() {
//bar width
       $('.bar').each(function (i) {
       var $bar = $(this);
       //creates count span
       $(this).append('<span class="count"></span>')
       setTimeout(function () {
       //sets width of bar
        $bar.css('width', $bar.attr('data-percent'));
        }, i * 100);
       });
// count in the bar graph
        $('.count').each(function () {
       $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).parent('.bar').attr('data-percent')
    }, {
        duration: 2000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
            $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + '%');
        }
    });
});

}, 500)
</script>



</div>
  




<style>
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,400italic|Montserrat:400,700);
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

html {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

caption, th, td {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

q, blockquote {
  quotes: none;
}
q:before, q:after, blockquote:before, blockquote:after {
  content: "";
  content: none;
}

a img {
  border: none;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, menu, nav, section, summary {
  display: block;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  color: #333;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  padding: 2%;
}

.wrap {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding: .5em 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}

h2 {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.0em;
  padding: .5em 0;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
}

ul li {
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: .85em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  clear: both;
}
ul li:before {
  content: "\2023";
  padding: 0 1em 0 0;
}

.bar {
  background: #3232ff;
  width: 0%;
  margin: .25em 0;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  transition: width 2s, background .2s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  clear: both;
}
.bar:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: #6666ff;
}
.bar .label {
  font-size: .75em;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #3d3d3d;
  width: 12em;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
.bar .label.light {
  background: #575757;
}

.count {
  position: absolute;
  right: .25em;
  top: .75em;
  padding: .15em;
  font-size: .75em;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact select,
#contact button[type="submit"] {
  font: 400 16px/18px "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#contact input[type="text"],
#contact select {
  width: 100%;
  height:60px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#contact input[type="text"]:hover,
#contact textarea:hover {
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
}
</style>



  </body>
</html>
```

Below is the Gs File.

```
/**
 * Handles HTTP GET requests to the published web app.
 * @return {HtmlOutput} The HTML page to be served.
 */

function doGet(){
    return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();    
}


function getSelectList() {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('10jSs0uoHOgO9VZusCa0ApyXmqISsHqsubIfRXiRPcQg');
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Projects Progress");
    var values = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
    return values;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}

// Fetch Values  
function fetchValues(result){
   Logger.log(result)
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('10jSs0uoHOgO9VZusCa0ApyXmqISsHqsubIfRXiRPcQg');
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Projects Progress"); //Enter your sheet Name
    var searchRange = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    for(var i = 0; i<searchRange.length;i++){
    if(searchRange[i][0] == result){ 

    var data  =  sheet.getRange((i+1),3,1,33).getValues();
    return data;
      Logger.log(data[0][0]);
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: What are the return values of `fetchValues()` and `getSelectList()`?

Comment: Also, where is your bar graph code?

Comment: fetch values returns a numerical data from the sheet depending on what option on the dropdown. getSelectList() returns a list of options from a google sheet. My bar graph code is at the bottom of my javascript code snippet.

Comment: The code which changes the bar graph is at the end of the javascript code snippet, but I see no element belonging to the `bar` class for which it selects?

Comment: The bar references a css class which changes the width of the bar depending on the data percent value.

Comment: See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You haven't included everything and so it's not possible to delve into what the issue is. In its current form, this code does not do what you describe and so without additional information I can't help further. Even hardcoding return values for `fetchValues` and `getSelectList`, [there is no bar graph that loads in the first place](https://jsfiddle.net/39zyhwo2/12/) let alone one which doesn't get altered. Pleae update your question with enough info to replicate what you're seeing.

Comment: Maybe I haven't made my question clear. What I am trying to get working is changing the variable `data-percent`. I have used `$('#test').data('data-percent', change);` but it doesn't change the value of the bar graph.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I have now included all of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*After setting the `data-percent` attribute of the bar, you need to call the function `start()` again.*

#### More Information:

In its current form, you only run the function `start()` 500ms after the page loads - and not again at any point. This is because it is defined exclusively inside the `setTimeout()` function call.

You can get it to update as you desire by removing it form inside the `setTimeout()` and then calling it after setting the `data-percent` attribute.

#### Code Modifications:

Firstly, move function `start()` outside of the `setTimeout()` and invoke it manually:

```js
function start() {
  //bar width
  $('.bar').each(function (i) {
    var $bar = $(this);
    //creates count span
    $(this).append('<span class="count"></span>')
    setTimeout(function () {
      //sets width of bar
      $bar.css('width', $bar.attr('data-percent'));
    }, i * 100);
  });
  // count in the bar graph
  $('.count').each(function () {
    $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
      Counter: $(this).parent('.bar').attr('data-percent')
    }, {
      duration: 2000,
      easing: 'swing',
      step: function (now) {
        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now) + '%');
      }
    });
  });  
}
setTimeout(start, 500)
```

This allows you to call `start()` as you desire, for example after `data-percent` has been set inside `displayValue()`:

```js
function displayValue(data){
  var change = data[0][0];
  $('.label').text(change); // to display the value in span
  document.getElementById('test').setAttribute('data-percent', '100%')
  start();
}
```